# { [Error: failed [405] HTTP method not allowed, supported methods: POST] stack: [Getter] }

Tags: javascript, http, meteor

I want to make a PredictionIO recommendation for a website built in meteor platform.
the code is:

```
getUserRecommendations: function (num) {
    var userId = Meteor.userId();
    check(userId, String);
    this.unblock();
    try {
        var result = HTTP.call('GET', "http://localhost:8000/queries.json",
        { params: { "user": [userId] , "num" : 4 } });
        return result;
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
        return "\n" +e;
    }
}
```

the error comes from Meteor server:

```
 { [Error: failed [405] HTTP method not allowed, supported methods: POST] stack: [Getter] }
```

Comment: clearly the server doesn't support `GET`, only `POST`

Comment: Broken server...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use POST instead of GET. Your server cannot handle GET requests